# Does the sun rise 'from' the east or 'in' the east?

Tags: prepositions

A quick web search suggests that the sun rises *in* the east, but I wonder if I can use *from* as well.
I thought it'd make more sense to say sth rises *from* somewhere, instead of *in* somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sense of **from** and **to** usage for this phrase is correct, however

> The sun rises **in** the east and sets **in** the west

is a colloquial phrase that is often used to signify **certainty**, and although

> The sun rises **from** the east

may be grammatically correct, if **from** and **to** are opposites, I have almost never heard

> The sun sets **to** the west

As an aside,

> The sun rises **in** the East

could also be used in a journalistic headline as a metaphor for the ascendency of China nowadays, or Japan in the 90's.

Comment: +1. Thank you. What is it then  that makes it awkward to say "The sun sets to the west"? Of course you can always answer these kinds of questions with "There's no why in language. It's just the way people have talked." But sometimes there is, as for this one, maybe.

Comment: @MJF It's just not commonly used.  If you said that the sun rose from the east and set to the west, I likely wouldn't notice, personally.  It sounds vaguely poetic, rather than what someone would say in daily usage.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sun is not moving, it's the rising that takes place in the east; we can't say it rises *from*. We have to say that "the sun rises in the east".